# Visual Studio C++ how to add header files in a prefix folder

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I cloned a github C++ repository. The repository is not a VS project. So I manually created a VS C++ blank project and added the files from the repo to the project. The files are not copied. This is not the problem.

The repo directory looks like this:

```
include\NTL\*.h
src\*.cpp
```

`*.h` means a bunch of header files and `*.cpp` means a bunch of `.cpp` source files.

The problem is that the `.cpp` files have `#include <NTL/*.h>` and when I build, VS fails to locate the header files (`No such file or directory`). Adding the path to the `include` to the Include Directories in project properties didn't help.

<strike>EDIT: After some experimenting, I've found that the error has nothing to do with the prefix `NTL` in `#include <NTL/*.h>` but with whether the files are copied into project directory. Even though the files appear in VS project view, they must be copied into the project directory.</strike>

EDIT: The only way I've managed to get the project to compile is to put the whole `NTL` directory containing header files in project directory. Include Directories and Additional Include Directories in project properties don't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Is the GitHub repository public? Can you provide a link to the GitHub repository?

Comment: @ShaneBishop It is public: https://github.com/libntl/ntl

Comment: There is an HTML page describing how to build the C++ project on Windows [here](https://github.com/libntl/ntl/blob/main/doc/tour-win.html). That in turns links to a YouTube video explaining how to build on Windows, which can be accessed [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2xijP2xATPI&feature=youtu.be).

Comment: You may be looking for `Project > Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories`. Mention the path to `include` directory there.

Comment: ***Adding the path to the include to the Include Directories in project properties didn't help*** I expect you somehow typed the wrong path. It has to be the root include folder that contains the NTL folder not the folder containing the headers.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That didn't work either.

Comment: @drescherjm I checked and the path is correct.

Comment: @ShaneBishop I followed the exact same steps in the video and got the same error.

Comment: @Myath I see you made an edit to your question. Did you solve your problem? If so, you can answer your own question if you wish.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to solve what seems to be a conflic tbetween "The files are not copied. This is not the problem." and "the error has ... to do with ... whether the files are copied into project directory". I find it very confusing.

Comment: Please [edit] question and answer to cleanup their overlap. Question should only describe the problem (possibly with details found out later and described in the "EDIT"s. All the solution parts/aspects should be only in your answer. Try to allow for a different solution to be found and described in an answer without contradicting your question. An answer can contradict a different answer, but should not contradict the question. This means that the question practically should not contain anything about "only way".

Comment: Did you follow the instructions? https://github.com/libntl/ntl/blob/main/src/NOTES - there are config scripts you presumably didn't run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All previous `No such file or directory` errors were the result of some combination of:

1. Mismatching project properties Configuration and Platform
2. Some `.h` files were actually missing from NTL github repo, e.g. `mach_desc.h`.

The solution to the problem consists of the following:

1. Under project `Properties > C/C++`, add the path to the `include` to `Additional Include Directories`.
2. VS project has a separate set of properties for each combination of Configuration and Platform. Make sure that step 1 applies to the active Configuration and Platform. E.g. If the project's currently configured to build for Debug x64 (active Configuration:Debug and Platform:x64), make sure that step 1 applies to Debug x64, and not something like Release Win32 or Release x64, etc.
3. Use the Windows/Linux-specific zip package from the Downloads page of the official website https://libntl.org/download.html

Comment: For the benefit of others coming across this answer, perhaps provide a link to the Downloads page and the official website.